# Can I rewrite a URL while keeping the sub-directories dynamic? (PHP)

Tags: php

I have little to no experience in PHP, but I've been assigned a task to rewrite the links of an old web to a new website that will replace it.

It's very tedious, I've mapped every link from the old site to the new one in an excel sheet.

Now my question being, can I rewrite one part of the directory and keep the sub directories following?

For example,

I've got (old site) `www.example/example-products/<product>`, the new website would be `www.example/products/<product>`.

Is it possible to rewrite `/products/ while keeping /<product>` dynamic? The reason being I could save a lot of time just creating 1 rewrite that changed `/products/` instead of having to create a static link for every individual product link. If that makes sense.

Comment: yes anything is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: Honestly not alot, this is pretty much my first time using PHP, (this task is way out of left field.) But with some quick googling I came up with this:

`rewrite ^/kam-products/ http://kam.com/products/ permanent; 
rewrite ^/documentation-matrix/ http://kam.com/documentation/ permanent;`
 
There are subdirectories in /products and /documentation that I want to remain dynamic as they've not changed.

Comment: Its not done in php, you need to be researching rewrites, fancy URLs etc. Where it matches in the path is just regex, and where it goes is just using the matches, gazillions of tutorials and examples on this subject.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input.

Comment: `^products/(.*)$ /example-products/$1`

Comment: You're a wonderful person